# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and others not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

Using breakpoints I found out that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not being called and neither are a constant declaration `static NSString *kAppKey = @"0000000";`

What I'm trying to do is set up push notifcations in my app but none of the essential functions are getting called. This isn't being called either/

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [PushWizard startWithToken:deviceToken andAppKey:kAppKey andValues:nil];

}
```

These are all in my AppDelegate. Any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Comment: What does your application do when it launches?

Comment: My app runs completely fine.

Comment: In that case you must verify some things.  1) Do other breakpoints work?  2) Is your class set up to be the application delegate (verify in main.m that you class is passed as the last argument to UIApplicationMain)  3) Is the method name correct?  It must be `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (two arguments).

Comment: breakpoints work in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` but not `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and few others in the AppDelegate. The class is also set up correctly in main.m and the method name and syntax are also correct.. Very confusing.